# minimum of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $v_1$ and $v_2$ are two independent random variables, and $V=\min(v_1,v_2)$. Where do I make mistakes if I use following steps to calculate $P(V{\leq}\mu)$?

$P(V{\leq}\mu)=P(V{\leq}\mu|v_1<v_2){\cdot}P(v_1<v_2)+P(V{\leq}\mu|v_1{\geq}v_2){\cdot}P(v_1{\geq}v_2)$;

$P(V{\leq}\mu|v_1<v_2)=\frac{P(V{\leq}\mu, v_1<v_2)}{P(v_1<v_2)}=\frac{P(v_1{\leq}\mu)}{P(v_1<v_2)}$

Comment: $P(V\leq \mu, \ v_1<v_2) = P(v_1\leq \mu, \ v_1< v_2)$. This may not be equal to $P(v_1\leq \mu)$.

Comment: Hint: you'll find it easier to calculate $P(V>\mu)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you made is that you wrote 
$$P(v_1\leq\mu) \neq P(v_q \leq \mu, v_1 \leq v_2)$$

One way to calculate $P(V\leq \mu)$

$$P(min(v_1,v_2)\leq \mu)=1-P(min(v_1,v_2)>\mu)$$

$$P(min(v_1,v_2)>\mu)=P(v_1>\mu,v_2>\mu)$$

By independence

$$P(min(v_1,v_2)>\mu)=P(v_1>\mu)P(v_2>\mu)$$

Finally,

$$P(min(v_1,v_2)\leq \mu)=1-P(v_1>\mu)P(v_2>\mu)$$

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but it is less laborious to compute $$\mathbb{P}(\mu < v_1, \mu <v_2)=\mathbb{P}(\mu < v_1)\mathbb{P}(\mu < v_2)$$
Because of independence, now we have calculated the probability that both random variables are greater than $\mu$, to calculate the probability that at least one of them is less than $\mu$ and therefore, that the minimum is less than $\mu$, compute 
$$1-\mathbb{P}(\mu < v_1)\mathbb{P}(\mu < v_2)$$